# how to change the page number of the url in android

Tags: android, json

I have a url which have a response in Json

lon=-0.1275&pg=0

I parsed the data from it and displayed in ListView, after displaying the 20 fields the above url should be changed to

lon=-0.1275&pg=1

ie the "pg" must change from 0 to as many pages. How to do that?

please provide me some help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a class level variable

```
int page = 0;
```

and when you make your url just append it like this:

```
url = "http://dentonsweb.com/app/html/android/get.php?what=Restaurants&lat=51.507222&lon=-0.1275&pg="+page;
```

and every time increment it with your pagination like this:

```
page+=10;
```

do the request again.

Answer (score 1):

You may use string's **replace** method to modify url string:

```
String url = "http://dentonsweb.com/app/html/android/get.php?what=Restaurants&lat=51.507222&lon=-0.1275&pg=0";

url = url.replace("&pg=0", "&pg=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way, NOT TESTED.

```
url = "http://dentonsweb.com/app/html/android/get.php?what=Restaurants&lat=51.507222&lon=-0.1275&pg=";
int i=0;
do{

         tempURL = url+i;
         // get tempURL response
         if(response==null) break;
         else
         {
           // parse response
           i++;
         }


}while(response!=null)
```